# inequality of Kernels dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Exercise

Let $U,V,W$ be $K$-finite-dimensional vector spaces, and $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(U,V)$, $g \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)$. Show that $\dim(\ker(g \circ f))\leq \dim(\ker(f))+\dim(\ker(g))$.

I have no idea how to show this result, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=f_{/\ker(g\circ f) }:\ker(g\circ f)\to V$.
By the rank formula  (applied to $h$) we have  $\dim(\ker(g\circ f))=\dim(\ker h)+\dim(\text{Im}h)$.
But $\ker (h)=\ker(f)\cap \ker(g\circ f)\subset \ker f$, it follow that $\dim(\ker h)\leq \dim(\ker f)$.
If $y\in \text{Im}(h)=f(\ker(g\circ f))$, then there is $x\in \ker(g\circ f)$ such that $y=f(x)$,  we have $g(y)=g(f(x))=(g\circ f)(x)=0$, this show that $\text{Im}(h)\subset \ker g$, it follow that $\dim(\text{Im} h)\leq \dim(\ker g)$.
Then $\dim(\ker(g\circ f))=\dim(\ker h)+\dim(\text{Im}h)\leq \dim(\ker f)+\dim(\ker g)$.